# Triple summation having $i,j,k$ as variables

Tags: summation

> Finding value of

> $(1)\ \displaystyle \mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}ijk$

> $(2)\ \displaystyle \mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq n}ijk$

For $(1) $ what I have done as

For without any restriction as

$ (S)=\displaystyle \mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i,j,k\leq n}ijk=\bigg(\sum^n_{i=1}i\bigg)^3=\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg)^3$

For exactly one equal

$\displaystyle S'=\displaystyle \mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i=j,k\leq n}ijk=\bigg(\sum^n_{j=1}j^2\bigg)\bigg(\sum^n_{k=1}k\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg)$

There are 3 such pairs $( i=j,j=k,k=i)$

All three equal

$S''=\displaystyle \mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i=j=k\leq n}ijk=\sum^n_{k=1}k^3=\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\bigg)^2$

Now we have

$\displaystyle \mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}ijk=S-3S'+S''$

$\displaystyle =\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\bigg(\frac{3n^2-n+4}{6}\bigg)$

But this is not correct, please tell me where I am wrong

Also please tell me part $2$

Comment: In your sum without restrictions you are double counting, as the same product can be arranged in different orders.

Comment: Thanku Zoe Allen. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: When you switch from the triple sum to the cube of the sum over i, you are making a mistake. That's because the triple sum only counts every product once, whereas the cube of the sum over i counts every product of 3 distinct numbers 6 times. Your strategy is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is smart. It just needs a little revision. Based on *[Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)*
we use
\begin{align*}
S_n&=\sum_{1\leq i,j,k\leq n}ijk=\left(\sum_{i=1}^ni\right)^3=\frac{1}{8}n^3(n+1)^3\\
S^{\prime}_n&=\sum_{1\leq i=j,k\leq n}ijk=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}j^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{12}n^2(n+1)^2(2n+1)\\
S^{\prime\prime}_n&=\sum_{1\leq i=j=k\leq n}ijk=\sum_{i=1}^ni^3=\frac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2\\
\color{blue}{S^{\prime\prime\prime}_n}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}ijk}\\
\end{align*}

> The identity we use to get $\color{blue}{S^{\prime\prime\prime}_n}$ is
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_n=6\cdot S^{\prime\prime\prime}_n+3\cdot S^{\prime}_n-2\cdot S^{\prime\prime}_n}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Note, in (1)

- we use $6$ times $S^{\prime\prime\prime}_n$ since we have $3!=6$ permutations of $(i,j,k)$ to respect.
- we also have to consider that $1\leq i=j,k\leq n$ also contains the cases $1\leq i=j\color{blue}{=}k\leq n$, which are also counted when we sum over $1\leq i=k,j\leq n$ and $1\leq i, j=k\leq n$. To compensate this overcounting we subtract $S^{\prime\prime}_n$ twice.

> We obtain according to (1) and the identities above
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S^{\prime\prime\prime}_n}&=\frac{1}{6}S-\frac{1}{2}S^{\prime}+\frac{1}{3}S^{\prime\prime}\\
> &=\frac{1}{48}n^3(n+1)^3-\frac{1}{24}n^2(n+1)^2(2n+1)+\frac{1}{12}n^2(n+1)^2\\
> &=\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2\left(n(n+1)-2(2n+1)+4\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2\left(n^2-3n+4\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2)}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with a comment from @JG.

The other wanted sum (2) can be derived from $S^{\prime\prime\prime}_{n}$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq n}}\color{blue}{ijk}
&=\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}ijk+\sum_{1\leq i=j<k\leq n}ijk+\sum_{1\leq i<j=k\leq n}ijk\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_{1\leq i=j=k\leq n}ijk\\
&=\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}ijk+\sum_{1\leq i=j<k\leq n}ijk+\sum_{1\leq k<i=j\leq n}ijk\\
&\qquad\qquad+\sum_{1\leq i=j=k\leq n}ijk\\
&=\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n}ijk+\sum_{1\leq i=j,k\leq n}ijk\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=S^{\prime\prime\prime}_n+S^{\prime}_n}\\
&=\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2)+\frac{1}{12}n^2(n+1)^2(2n+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2(n^2+5n+6)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2(n+2)(n+3)}
\end{align*}
in accordance with a comment from @JG.

Comment: Thanku epic163sqrt got it. Also please tell me what I add or subtract in part (1) formula to get part (2)

Comment: @PritiBisht: You're welcome. I'v added some info regarding (2).

Answer (score 3):

It is better to make each summation explicit.  You can then evaluate them one by one.  You are looking for
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{j=2}^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}ijk$$
where the $2$ comes because we require $i \lt j$.  Now evaluate from the inside out, so this becomes
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{j=2}^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}ijk=\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{j=2}^{k}\frac{j(j-1)}2jk$$
Keep going.  For the second one, you just update the lower limits to $1$ and the upper $i$ limit to $j$.

Comment: The OP's sum is over $ijk$, not $1$.

Comment: @J.G.  Thanks.  Fixed

Comment: Thanku Ross Millikan got it. Can you please tell me why I am not getting correct answer from my solution. I. E where I am wrong.

Comment: If $i,j,k$ are all different your $S$ counts $1,2,3$ six times for all the permutations of $i,j,k$.  Your sum only counts it once where $i \lt j \lt k$

Comment: @PritiBisht If you try this answer's technique, you'll also need a few of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples). If memory serves, you should find the answers are$$\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2(n-1)(n-2),\,\frac{1}{48}n^2(n+1)^2(n+2)(n+3).$$

Comment: Thanku Ross Millikan for second one you mean $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=1}\sum^{k}_{j=1}\sum^{j}_{i=1}ijk$

Comment: Yes, that is right